# SelectAll items in WPF datagrid is throwing System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the following datagrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridOrderItems" Margin="4,10,2,70"
VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray" AlternatingRowBackground="Beige"  AlternationCount="2" 
SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False" SelectionChanged="dataGridOrderItems_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resource Id" Binding="{Binding ResourceId}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resource Name" Binding="{Binding DisplayTitle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding ResourceType}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Date" Binding="{Binding OrderDate, StringFormat=\{0:d\}}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select" CellTemplate="{StaticResource template}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu >
            <MenuItem Header="Select All" Click="SelectAllDatagridOrderItems"  />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Which is binded to the following data source:

```
public class CustomerOrdersEntity
{
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayTitle { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public string ResourceType { get; set; }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public string OrderDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

I'm attempting to implement a select all item using the following:

```
public void SelectAllDatagridOrderItems(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridOrderItems.ItemsSource == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            "No resources are currently loaded! Please select a customer to continue.",
            "No resources loaded",
            MessageBoxButton.OK,
            MessageBoxImage.Asterisk);

        return;
    }

    dataGridOrderItems.SelectAll();
}
```

However this throws the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in PresentationFramework.dll

How should I approach this? I thought of iterating over the itemsource and updating `IsChecked` to `true` for each row but it seemed like unnecessary overkill and I'm sure there must be a more simple solution that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you disabled multiple selection?

Comment: @LexLi I have not, but only the row can be selected at a time (SelectionUnit:FullRow)

Comment: Sorry - I'm wrong. I have, yes. To be clear - you can update multiple rows, but you cannot select more than one at a time. When I say select all what I'm trying to say is that I want to check all rows to be selected. I think your comment exposed a huge flaw in my thought process since it's not a true selection but checking a checkbox.